# React Query: Invalidate all "useInfiniteQuery" cache data

Tags: reactjs, tanstackreact-query

I have a page where data is loaded using useInfiniteQuery, however, the cached data do not update upon invalidation after a successful mutation. Here are the related snippets of code:

**Infinite Query hook**

```
export interface UseGetInfiniteProgramCategoriesQuery {
   params: URLSearchParams;
}

export const useGetInfiniteProgramCategoriesQuery = ({
   params,
}: UseGetInfiniteProgramCategoriesQuery) => {
   return useInfiniteQuery({
      queryKey: ["program-categories"],
      queryFn: async ({ pageParam }) => {
         params.set("cursor", pageParam.toString());

         const res = await api.get("/program-categories", { params });

         const [data, count] = res.data?.data;

         return {
            data,
            hasNextPage: pageParam * +params.get("perPage")! < count,
            cursor: pageParam,
         };
      },
      initialPageParam: 1,
      getNextPageParam: (lastPage) =>
         lastPage.hasNextPage ? lastPage.cursor + 1 : null,
      select: (data) => data.pages.flatMap((page) => page.data),
   });
};
```

**Query Invalidation after Mutation**

```
queryClient.invalidateQueries({
   queryKey: ["program-categories"],
});
```

I wanted to invalidate all data within the scope of the "program-categories" query key. Because in its current state, the page needs to be reloaded for the changes to reflect.

Comment: queryClient.invalidateQueries({
   queryKey: ["program-categories"],
   refetchActive: true, // Ensures active instances of the query are refetched
});

Comment: Thank you so much, I am literally searching this for hours...

Comment: did it work, if it did, let me post as the answer?

Comment: @AdesojiAlu Yes it worked. You may post that as an answer.

Comment: i have done it, please mark as answer